# Java.sql.SQLException doing a SELECT

Tags: java, sql, sqlexception

When I try to execute this code:

```
    try {

        pstm = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Menu WHERE (menuName LIKE '?%')");
        pstm.setString(1,searchedMenu.getMenuName());
        rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Menu menu=new Menu();
            menu.setMenuId(rs.getInt("menuId"));
            menu.setMenuName(rs.getString("menuName"));
            temp.add(menu);
        }
```

I get the error in the subject, why? My purpose is to search a string or a part of it.
Thank you.

Edit: the error is:
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
And it is referred to this line:
pstm.setString(1,searchedMenu.getMenuName());

Comment: I don’t know which error this is, how `java.sql` works, or which SQL you’re using. Try `WHERE menuName LIKE (? || '%')`, though.

Comment: One of **many** reasons why it may fail, and until you post the actual error messages we will not know the actual reasons, is that your parameter may include single quotes.

Comment: @GermannArlington: That’s not supposed to matter in parametrized queries…

Comment: @minitech I noticed the enclosing quotes, what I did not realise is that they will prevent parameter replacement completely. I know that in parametrized queries the quotes are escaped, what I thought is that it may not be escaped correctly to work with enclosing quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is likely from the fact that you don't have any parameter markers to set, because you put the question mark into the string:

```
menuName LIKE '?%'
```

So that when you do this:

```
pstm.setString(1,searchedMenu.getMenuName());
```

There is nothing to set, and it will throw an error.  If you check the stack trace, it's likely that you're seeing a message about the number of parameter markers.

You should concatenate the percent into the string in Java.  Concatenating it in the SQL will provide less consistent results, varying by RDBMS.

So I would recommend writing your SQL with a parameter like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Menu WHERE (menuName LIKE ?)
```

And then setting the parameter in the java code like this:

```
pstm.setString(1, searchedMenu.getMenuName() + "%");
```

Also consider trimming the menu name, if you know there will be spaces.  Your results may not be as you expect if you have a percent sign after a bunch of spaces.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine! I've modified the line like in this way:
pstm.setString(1,"%"+searchedMenu.getMenuName()+"%");

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Menu WHERE (menuName LIKE ?)

pstm.setString(1, searchedMenu.getMenuName() + "%");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
"SELECT * FROM Menu WHERE menuName LIKE ?"
```

And then append `%` to string that your are binding to this placeholder

```
pstm.setString(1,searchedMenu.getMenuName()+"%");
```